# What methods are used to crawl a website that only offers a search bar for navigation

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

How would you go about crawling a website such that you can index every page when there is only really a search bar for navagation like the following sites.

https://plejehjemsoversigten.dk/

https://findadentist.ada.org/

Do people just brute force the search queries, or is there a method that's usually implemented to index these kinds of websites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be several ways to approach your issue (however if the owner of a resource does not want the resource to be crawled, that might be really challenging)

- Check `robots.txt` of a resource. It might give you a clue on the site structure.
- Check `sitemap.xml` of a resource. It might give URLs of the pages a resource owner wishes to be public
- Use alternative indexers (like google). Use advanced syntax narrowing the scope of search to a particular site (like `site:your.domain`)
- Use breaches in site design. For example first site from your list does not have a minimal search string so that you can search for, say, `a` and get 800 results containing `a`. Then list remaining letters.
- Having search result crawl all the links on the search result items pages since there often might be related pages listed.